# How to inject something in custom validator?

Tags: c#, ninject, repository-pattern, wcf-ria-services, customvalidator

I'm using CustomValidation for one entity and I want to inject Repository in it. Validation method must be static. Is there any way to inject object in static context other than service location?

Here's my metadata:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(BillPosition.BillPositionsMetadata))]
[CustomValidation(typeof(BillPositionValidator), "ValidateBillPositionsCount")]
public partial class BillPosition
{
    internal sealed class BillPositionsMetadata
    {
        private BillPositionsMetadata() { }

        public int BillId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's validator code:

```
public class BillValidator
{
    [Inject]
    public static IRepository Repository { get; set; }

    public static ValidationResult ValidateBillPositionsCount(BillPosition bill, ValidationContext context)
    {
        ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.Success;

        /* Repository wasn't injected and I get null reference exception */
        var billPositions = Repository.BillPositions.Count(position => position.BillId == bill.BillId);
        if (bill.BillPositions.Count == 0 && billPositions == 0)
        {
            result = new ValidationResult("Invalid positions count", new[] { "BillPositions" });
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not any way to inject into custom validators.  A Service Locator or some form of reflection could be used to either access a property or method on the instance the validator is being executed on.  You can access this instance through the ValidationContext.

http://www.jaltiere.com/index.php/2010/05/04/ninject-with-mvc-and-validationattributes/

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the IoC and resolve the dependency. Like I am using Unity. In these cases I would call Bootstrapper.Unity.Resolve("NameOfMyDependency")

Answer (score 0):

If you are not resolving the validator from the dependency injection container, you can still resolve the repository directly using some kind of service locator:

```
public class BillValidator
{
    static BillValidator()
    {
        Repository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository>();
    }

    public static IRepository Repository { get; set; }
}
```

That way you can initialize the validator using the `new`-keyword:

```
var validator = new BillValidator();
```

and you still get the dependency resolved in the validator.

Due to the fact that the repository gets resolve in the type initializer it will be executed only once per type in your applcation. All instances of the validator will use the same repository.

This code works when working with Unity, but should be equivalent when working with MEF or other containers.